# Why idris2 can't proof that div 1 2 < 1 = True?

Tags: proof, idris2

When I write:

```
div_1_2_lower_than_1 : div (S Z) 2 < (S Z) = True
div_1_2_lower_than_1 = Refl
```

I get error:

```
While processing right hand side of div_1_2_lower_than_1. Can't solve constraint
between: True and compare (1 `div` 2) 1 == LT.
```

Meanwhile when I write:

```
minus_1_2_lower_than_1 : minus (S Z) 2 < (S Z) = True
minus_1_2_lower_than_1 = Refl
```

Everything is fine.
Why?

**Updated:**

I used Data.Nat and natDiv for some reason fundamentally not validated.

```
div_1_2_eq_0 : div (S Z) (S (S Z)) = 0
div_1_2_eq_0 = Refl
```

Error:

```
While processing right hand side of div_1_2_eq_0. Can't solve constraint between: 0 and divNat 1 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is right. The implementation of `div` isn't exported so the type checker can't reduce it

```
export partial
divNat : Nat -> Nat -> Nat

public export
Integral Nat where
  div = divNat
```

You can try using `divNatNZ` instead, which is public exported, though for some reason it expects the non-zero proof explicitly.